# Changing UIButton image between selected and default

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have the following that I use to load local html files in a UIWebView.

```
- (IBAction)loadLocalFile:(id)sender

{
UIButton *tmp = sender;
int tag = (int)tmp.tag;
NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"elec%i", tag];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@""];
NSString *filePath = @"";

switch (tag) {
    case 1:
    {
        filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:fileName ofType:@"html"];
        break;
    }
    case 2:
    {
        filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:fileName ofType:@"html"];
        break;
    }
    default:
        break;
}

url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
[self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
}
```

I'm trying to find a way that when a user presses one of the buttons the button image changes (basic red square to emphasize the location) and when the user presses another button in the view the first button returns to the original state whilst the selected one changes to the new image…
Any input is greatly appreciated.
Thanks!!!

i've tried

```
button.selected = !button.selected;
```

it changes the image to the boxed image that I want, but when another button is pressed the previous does not return to the original state.

Double pressing the same button does return it to its original state though.

Answer (score 0):

after looking around i found this solution:

```
// Unselect all the buttons in the parent view
for (UIView *button in tmp.superview.subviews) {
if ([button isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
    [(UIButton *)button setSelected:NO];
}
}

// Set the current button as the only selected one
[tmp setSelected:YES];
```